# Parsing incoming Json Data in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift3, swift4, decodable

Regarding to incoming Json data from Server, `dataString` printed successfully as below,

```
Debug;
Response: '[{"SSID": "ASUS_5G_2.4G_EXT", "RSSI": -66}, {"SSID": "Rattus_WiFi", "RSSI": -72}, {"SSID": "mgts371", "RSSI": -75}]'
```

I want to convert it to following format to use it's objects based on my Struct.

```
let scannedNetworks = [["SSID": "ASUS_5G_2.4G_EXT", "RSSI": -66], ["SSID": "Rattus_WiFi", "RSSI": -72], ["SSID": "mgts371", "RSSI": -75]]
```

However, when i `print scannedNetworks`, i am getting following error

```
ERROR:The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

Swift Code;

```
static var scannedNetworks = [Network]()

static func URLrequest() {
     //...
     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
     guard let data = data, error == nil else {
         print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
         return
     }

     let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
     print("Response: \(dataString)")
     do {
         scannedNetworks = try JSONDecoder().decode([Network].self, from: data)
         print(scannedNetworks)
     } catch {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
     }
 }
task.resume()
}

struct Network: Decodable {
var SSID: String
var RSSI: Int
init(SSID: String, RSSI: Int) {
    self.SSID = SSID
    self.RSSI = RSSI

}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case SSID
    case RSSI
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let SSID = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .SSID)
    let RSSI = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .RSSI)
    self.init(SSID: SSID, RSSI: RSSI)
}
```

Comment: The response shouldn't include the single quote at the start and at the end. If you can't control the response, then remove these two characters before deserializing.

Comment: Thanks, i have removed single quotes from dataString and convert it to data again (dataString.data(using: .utf8)!) and that's worked.